# Use enum to determine type of return result ( a hack using Macro )

Tags: c++, enums, macros, c++14, x-macros

I have many types of game-object that are related together is some ways.
All relations is implemented by `Map<K1,K2>`.

```
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

template<class K1,class K2> class Map{ //N:N relation
     public: std::vector<K2*> getK2(K1* k1){/* some code */return std::vector<K2*>();} 
     public: std::vector<K1*> getK1(K2* k2){/* some code */return std::vector<K1*>();}
     //... various function ...
};
```

Here is the hub class `GameRelation` that facilitates all relation query :-
(just an example, no need to pay attention to all detail)

```
class Human{};   class House{};    class Dog{};
class GameRelation{
    public:
    #define RELATION(A,B,EnumName) Map<A,B> Map##EnumName;  \
    enum EnumName##Enum{EnumName};   \
    std::vector<B*> getAllRight(EnumName##Enum e,A* a){  \
        return Map##EnumName.getK2(a);  \
    }
    //... various function ...
    RELATION(Human,House,Own) 
    //I can insert any relation that I want
};
```

The above macro expands into something like :-

```
Map<Human,House> MapOwn; 
enum OwnEnum{Own};   
std::vector<House*> getAllRight(OwnEnum e,Human* a){  
    return MapOwn.getK2(a);  
}
```

Here is how it can be used ([full demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/521b3802064cdeee)):-

```
int main() {
    GameRelation gameRelation;
    std::vector<House*> houses=gameRelation.getAllRight(GameRelation::Own,new Human()); 
    //get all "House" that is "Own" by a "Human" 
    return 0;
}
```

After some testing, it works good.    Everyone is happy with the magical result.

However, my conscious tell me that it is a hack.
 It is also a little bad for content-assist (e.g. intellisense) and automatic refactoring.
I also need the <s>awesome</s> hacking **X-MACRO** if I want to move their implementation to `.cpp`.

**Question:**

- Is there any elegant (less hack) way?     What is it?
  "No" can be a valid answer.
- Is **X-MACRO** the (professional) way to go when I need such (strange) feature?

Comment: `using namespace std;`? Aw come on, you're better than that...

Comment: It looks like you are trying to reinvent the relational data model with enums and macros in an imperative programming language. Have you considered just using something like SQLite instead? You may have a table "house", a table "human" and a table "house_ownership" with foreign keys to the former two.

Comment: @Quentin Agree, that is just for demo sake.  It is a default setting of "ideone".

Comment: @Christian Hackl  Yes, I also feel it, but I have never known there is such library. Thank.  Does SQLite use hash-function?  I hate hash, it is very slow. (I have profiled std::unordered_map.)

Comment: @javaLover: I have no idea how SQLite is actually implemented, but it's the standard industry solution when you need a local file-based relational database. It's used by Android, iOS, Firefox and the latest Visual Studio IDE, for example. However, it may be the wrong choice if you need something completely in-memory and cannot afford the I/O operations.

Comment: @ChristianHackl Apparently [they thought of that already](https://sqlite.org/inmemorydb.html) :)

Comment: @Quentin: Good point, although I cannot say if this is really a good solution as a replacement for elaborate data structures in the DB client code when it comes to game development. I've never used SQLite like that myself. But the OP may give it a try.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
struct GameRelation{
    template <typename A, typename B>
    struct Relation {
        std::vector<B*> getAllRight(A* a) {
            return map.getK2(a);
        }

    private:
        Map<A, B> map;
    };

    Relation<Human, House> own;
};

int main() {
    GameRelation gameRelation;
    std::vector<House*> houses = gameRelation.own.getAllRight(new Human()); 
}
```

Comment: An only (minor) disadvantage I found is that it is less encapsulated - I will access field "own" directly.

Comment: @javaLover why is this a problem? `Relation` is specifically intended to be an accessor, and any undesired operations on it can be disallowed simply by not providing them.

Comment: That is a word of wisdom.

Comment: May you tell what this technique is called, please?... the technique to create a class that dedicated to contain only fields of a single/common type ...

Comment: @javaLover I am not aware of any common name for it.